# Separate geom_linerange by group within a facet in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

Let's say I have the following data:

```
test = read.table(text = 'condition1 condition2 estimate std_error name
a x .466 .09 name_1
a y .343 .131 name_1
b x .466 .09 name_1
b y .343 .131 name_1
a x .466 .09 name_2
a y .343 .131 name_2
b x .466 .09 name_2
b y .343 .131 name_2', header = T, stringsAsFactors = T)


ggplot(data = test, aes(x = estimate, y = condition1, fill = condition2, group = condition2)) +
    geom_point(color = 'black') +
    geom_linerange(aes(xmin = estimate - std_error,
                       xmax = estimate + std_error), color = 'black') +
    ylab(NULL) +
    facet_grid(name ~ .,
               scales = "free_y",
               space = "free_y",
               switch = 'y')
```

[image]

I'm trying to separate out the `x` and `y` lines as separate lines within the `b` and `a` conditions `within` a given facet (`name_1` and `name_2`). But my code as is is putting the two lines as the same y-value, so they're overlapping. What is the best way to separate the lines?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adjust `width = X` to taste.

```
...
 geom_point(color = 'black', position = position_dodge(width = 1)) +
  geom_linerange(aes(xmin = estimate - std_error,
                     xmax = estimate + std_error), color = 'black',
                     position = position_dodge(width = 1)) +
...
```

[image]

Or here with some more aesthetic tweaks:

```
ggplot(data = test, aes(x = estimate, y = condition1, fill = condition2, group = condition2)) +
  geom_linerange(aes(xmin = estimate - std_error,
                     xmax = estimate + std_error), color = 'black',
                 position = position_dodge(width = 0.5)) +
  geom_point(color = 'black', size = 2, shape = 21, position = position_dodge(width = 0.5)) +
  ylab(NULL) +
  facet_grid(name ~ .,
             scales = "free_y",
             space = "free_y",
             switch = 'y') +
  theme(panel.grid.major.y = element_blank())
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I had tried `position = dodge` within `aes`, but it didn't do anything. Didn't realize you had to wrap it in `position_dodge`.